# avoiding duplication in the assignment operator of a derived class

Tags: c++, class, assignment-operator

Consider the assignment operators in classes `Parent` and `Child`, below.

```
#include <iostream>
class Parent 
{
public:
  Parent(){};
  virtual ~Parent(){};
  Parent& operator=(const Parent& other){mP = other.mP; return *this;};

  void setP(double inP){mP = inP;};
  double getP(){return mP;};
protected:
  double mP;
};


class Child : public virtual Parent
{
public:
  Child(){};
  virtual ~Child(){};
  Child& operator=(const Child& other)
  {
     mC = other.mC;
     mP = other.mP;// this line
     return *this;
  };

  void setC(double inC){mC = inC;};
  double getC(){return mC;};
protected:
  double mC;
};
```

Is here a way to avoid the duplicate line `mP = other.mP;`?

The reason I am asking is that as the number of bases get higher and the inheritance structure gets more complicated, it is easy to lose track of members.

**EDIT**

The reason I need to implement the `operator=` is that it needs to check some things before the assignments.

Comment: `Parent::operator=(other);` Same as with any other method.

Comment: I think you're stuck with assigning the members individually. Don't forget the `return *this;`

Comment: In your case the simplest way is not to overload assignment operators at all and let the compiler silently do the job for you.

Comment: @101010 or in other words: prefer the rule-of-0 rather than the rule-of-3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just call the Parent operator:

```
Child& operator=(const Child& other)
{
     mC = other.mC;
     Parent::operator=(other);
     return *this;
}
```

Or really, don't implement either operator since both are trivial!

Comment: @AndyG there's no reason for self-assignment checking, don't believe everything Meyers says.

Comment: Yes, I suppose it's preference. Prefer protecting those touching my code in the future from themselves.

Comment: @AndyG it's not a preference, IMHO it's stupid. You optimize your code for the worst case.

Comment: @101010: At first your comment of it being "stupid" bothered me a bit. Then I decided to google around for some more discussion on the issue. After reading up on the literature surrounding self-assignment, I retract my earlier comment. However I do not believe it's necessarily "stupid", but perhaps motivated by a sense of distrust in my fellow programmer to know how/when to handle self-assignment upon modifying the class in the future. So thank you for pushing me to become better educated on the matter.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to avoid this issue is to remove both of your `operator=` functions.

The compiler-generated `operator=` applies `operator=` to each member variable and base class, which is just what you were trying to do anyway.

Re-implementing the wheel just makes your code harder to read and maintain -- and sometimes less efficient.

Comment: What if I had a `const` member? It wouldn't work then, would it?

Comment: @Furihr You'd have to write all your own special member functions if you had a non-static const member ; but it does not make much sense to assign an object that has a member like that. I don't know of any use-cases for it.

Comment: Imagine a finite difference scheme. The order of derivation in many cases could be constant.

Comment: You wouldn't use a const member variable for that

Comment: Why not? It must be constant in many cases. Since every differencing scheme must have an order of derivation, we define it as a member of their common abstract base class. And it can't be `static consexpr` since it is defined at run-time or within each class.

Comment: Because it would mess up all of your implicitly generated functions like operator=, for no reason. It makes the object not copyable too. Just use a non-const member and don't change it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Child& operator=(const Child& other)   {
     mC = other.mC;
     mP = other.mP; 
}
```

you can invoke the assignment operator of the parent prior to the child specific assignment in this way:

```
 Child& operator=(const Child& other)
  {
     Parent::operator=(other);
     mC = other.mC;
     return *this;
  };
```